# Lua: How do you update a variable that's in an event?

Tags: if-statement, events, lua, scope, roblox

The issue I'm running into is that my variable isn't updating after an event. Here is my code:

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local intermission = 15 -- time in seconds

local AmountOfPlayers = #Players:GetPlayers() -- starts at zero
local minPlayers = 1


Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player) -- updates amount of players in server
    AmountOfPlayers = AmountOfPlayers + 1
end)

Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(Player) -- updates amount of players in server
    AmountOfPlayers = AmountOfPlayers - 1
end)
```

Below, this if-statement is not running since AmountOfPlayers is not equal to minPlayers.

```lua
while intermission > 0 do
    if AmountOfPlayers >= minPlayers then
    print("SUCCESS")                
    end
end
```

I have a scope issue of the variable AmountOfPlayers. I'm not sure how to fix this, so any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: what is intermisssion? are your event callbacks being triggered?

Comment: Make `AmountOfPlayers` global.  Or make sure your `while intermission` statement is inside the scope of local `AmountOfPlayers`

Comment: `Players:GetPlayers()` is already global. Why not just call that any time you need to check how many players are in the game?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a wait() in your while loop. This is most likely what leads to the script crashing and not working. So it should look like:

```
while intermission > 0 do
    wait()
    if AmountOfPlayers >= minPlayers then
    print("SUCCESS")                
    end
end
```

**OR**

If that isn't the problem, instead of making:

`local AmountOfPlayers = #Players:GetPlayers()`

Instead:

```
local AmountOfPlayers = Players:GetChildren()
```

And Remove the two functions.